# How to get rid of "®" and "™" in a string?

Tags: php, regex, string, html-entities

I have a string like `"Welcome to McDonalds®: I'm loving it™"` ... I want to get rid of `":"`, `"'"`, `®` and `™` symbols. I have tried the following so far:

```
$string = "Welcome to McDonalds®: I'm loving it™";
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]/', '', $string);
```

But on the output I receive:

`"Welcome to McDonaldsreg Im loving ittrade"`... so `preg_replace` somehow converts `®` to `'reg'` and `™` to `'trade'`, which is not good for me and I cannot understand, why such a conversion happens at all.

How do I get rid of this conversion?

***Solved:*** Thanks for ideas, guys. I solved the problem:

```
$string = preg_replace(
    array('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]/', '/&[^\s]*;/'), 
    '', 
    preg_replace(
        array('/&[^\s]*;/'), 
        '', 
        htmlentities($string)
    )
);
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark the right answer with "accepted answer"!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're probably having the special characters in [entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) form, i.e. ® is really `&reg;` in your string. So it's not seen by the replacement operation.

To fix this, you could filter for the &SOMETHING; substring, and remove them. There might be built-in methods to do this, perhaps [html_entity_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking to replace only the mentioned characters, use

```
$cleaned = str_replace(array('®','™','&reg;','&trade;', ":", "'"), '', $string);
```

Regular string replacement methods are usually faster and there is nothing *in your example* you want to replace that would need the pattern matching power of the Regular Expression engine.

*EDIT due to comments:*
If you need to replace character patterns (as indicated by the solution you gave yourself), a Regex is indeed more appropriate and practical.

<s>In addition, I'm sure McD requires both symbols to be in place if that slogan is used on any public website</s>

Comment: what's a problem with regex? As for McDonalds, this string is from my imagination ))) nothing related to the real life.

Comment: Why did this get a downvote? The PHP documentation in fact states "If you don't need fancy replacing rules (like regular expressions), you should always use this function [str_replace] instead of ereg_replace() or preg_replace()."

Comment: I downvoted because it's silly to use an array for every variant of values rather than a regular expression in this case. Do you really want an array of every possible `&[#a-z0-8];` variant? Do you know how large that would be? Please don't take offense.

Comment: @Gordon: I didn't down voted you but when you `str_replace()` **with an array** it's usually slower than using `preg_replace()`.

Comment: @Jonathan the OP asked for `want to get rid of ":", "'", ® and ™ symbols`. Not the entire range of HTML entities.

Comment: Gordon, the OP gave us an example. This should be evident by the OP's "solution," `&[^\s]*;` That removes all variants of `&[#a-z0-9]+;`

Comment: @Alix I cannot confirm that. A quick benchmark I just did suggests different.

Comment: @Jonathan the solution wasn't there yet when I wrote the answer and it wasn't there when you downvoted me either ;) But it's okay. If the OP really wanted everything removed, then, of course, a Regex is appropriate.

Comment: @Gordon, I gathered that the McD's string was an *example*, and as such the specifics of it aren't the issue. If the user only expected to remove &trade; and &reg;, then I wouldn't have downvoted you, but I felt it was evident that it was a general example, and not an exclusive issue. No hard feelings though :)

Comment: @Jonathan To me it wasn't obvious. I've changed some bits in my answer to reflect this now. No hard feelings.

Answer (score 0):

® is `&reg;`, and ™ is `&trade;`. As such, you'll want to remove anything that follows
the pattern `&[#0-9a-z]+;` before-hand:

```
$input = "Remove all &trade; and &reg; symbols, please.";
$string = preg_replace("/&[#0-9a-z]+;/i", "", $input);
```

Comment: What about numerical character references like `&#169;` or `&#174;`.

Comment: Sorry, Gumbo. I was addressing the specific need, but you're right. I've updated to include other non-alpha variants.

Comment: "I want to get rid of ":", "'", ® and ™ symbols" - I don't think he wants to remove all HTML entities.

Comment: Alix Axel, the OP gave an example using &reg; and &trade;. Note the OP's "solution" includes `&[^\s]*;` That is practically the same thing I provided above.